# Google picker selected file callback

Tags: javascript, google-api, google-drive-api, google-oauth, google-picker

i have integrated and try to use the google picker api
[google picker api](https://developers.google.com/picker/docs)
but can i turn the callback into file ?
so i can upload the file to my server

```js
function pickerCallback(data) { 
  if (data.action == google.picker.Action.PICKED) {
    var fileId = data.docs[0].id; alert('The user selected: ' + fileId); 
  } 
}
```

---

Answer (score 1):

### Once you have the `fileId`, you can download the file as explained in the documentation for [Download files with the Drive API](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-downloads)

Unfortunately, there is no sample for Browser Javascript, but you use e.g. [XML HttpRequests](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_http.asp).

Sample:

```js
//provided you already have the following line from previous steps:
oauthToken = authResult.access_token;

var doc = data[google.picker.Response.DOCUMENTS][0];
var mimeType = doc[google.picker.Document.MIME_TYPE];

var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("GET", "https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/"+fileId+'?alt=media', true);
xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization','Bearer '+oauthToken);
xhr.responseType = 'arraybuffer'
xhr.onload = function(){
    var base64 = 'data:' + mimeType + ';base64,' + base64ArrayBuffer(xhr.response);
//now you have the file content as binary data (ArrayBuffer) - proceed as desired
}
xhr.send();
```

Note:

you can modify `xhr.responseType` to e.g. `blob` or another [responseType](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/responseType) depending on your situation.

Alternatively you could also perform a [Fetch request](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) to 'https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files' to obtain the file blob.